# How to use phrasal verbs with prepositions without thinking which i have to use

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I am frustrated about unawareness how to use up/down/with etc. with phrasal verbs properly.Being from Ukraine can't really understand if it means something or it is just a combination of words. So, my question is: **does exist the literature, which explains how to use the phrasal verbs with prep. and imagine what is means without learning by heart? **

Comment: Unfortunately, which preposition to use in a phrasal verb in English is rather like  knowing which prepositions govern which case, or which prefix to use for the perfective in Ukrainian.

Comment: Here's a pretty [Extensive List of Phrasal Verbs](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/list-of-phrasal-verbs/). Whether you need to *learn* to distinguish between, say, ***back up*** and ***back down*** on a case-by-case basis (as opposed to being able to "intuit" the difference based on the general senses of those two prepositions) is essentially a matter for you to decide. Quite likely some of those differences will make more sense to speakers of certain languages in particular, but I don't know where Ukrainian fits in that context.